# Postgres and c# - DateTime with timezone confusion

Tags: c#, postgresql, datetime

Hopefully not a repost of another... a rather simple question, but I think I'm fundamentally confused about how dates/times with timezones are handled between Postgres and c#.

Simple situation, at one point in the program I call DateTime.Now and save to a variable 'now'. This is inserted into a Postgres DB.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("createdat", now);
```

Great. The column that this is inserted into is of type "timestamp with time zone". When I view the result from something like DataGrip or DBeaver the raw data is exactly what I want (I think).

```
2021-03-09 15:07:51
```

Later on I query this table in a rather simple way.

```
SELECT createdat FROM mytable WHERE mycondition;
```

I cast it as a c# DateTime type and populate a class with it.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    myClass.createdAt = (DateTime) reader["createdat"];
}
```

However, the value is populated as the following:

```
3/9/2021 10:07:51 AM
```

Something is not working here. First, if the column in the DB is of timestamp with time zone, where is the time zone information? Second, if the time zone is working, since it is being both populated and queried from the same computer, why is there a discrepancy? Third, and the pressing issue, how do I solve this? Must I explicitly define the time zone? I'm confused as to why it is returning different data... Hopefully, someone can help me out.

Comment: To be clear, in case it wasn't, I am using Npgsql as a data provider for interacting with the DB.

Comment: Why would you think that `DateTime.Now` is timezone-aware?

Comment: I'm not exactly saying that it is either. Somewhere along the way, a time zone is being brought into the equation (it seems). If DateTime.Now has no time zone, and I never explicitly refer to one, the question I am left with is where is the translation to another time occurring?

Comment: The timezone is set without changing the date/time value, which ends up completely different after a round-trip between the front-end and the DB. Search for `DateTime.SpecifyKind` and `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`.

Comment: That's not very clear to me though. Why would it be different when it is being requested by the same computer that created and inserted the value in the first place? I ask because then there would be no reason to change time zones... if that's even what is happening.

Who determines the time zone?

Answer (score 0):

I think Dbeaver is changing the time zone, but the data inserted is the same you get on c#. Try to check directly on the server using commandline because maybe dbeaver is changing it to diplay on your pc